# Where is the root folder of a Meteor app?

Tags: meteor

I am trying to set up SSL for my meteor app and need to verify control of my domain for the SSL certificate provider. They want me to place a sslfile.txt file in the root folder of my domain.

I wanted to confirm that the root folder is the `app/` folder. Is this correct?

The file should open when I go to www.myapp.com/sslfile.txt

Reference (Method 3):

https://support.comodo.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/791/16/alternative-methods-of-domain-control-validation-dcv

Comment: Hi - I posted a link with the SSL setup rules (method 3). Thx.

Answer (score 3):

I think that's `/public` folder

[documentation here](https://docs.meteor.com/#/basic/filestructure)